# Mongoose query middleware/pre-find hooks, what does 'this' refer to?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I have been learning about mongoose query middleware and that when using `this` within a query middleware function it refers to the query object.

However, I am struggling to visualise what the query object actually is and how I can use it. For example, if I had the code:

```
let query = Model.findById(req.params.id);
```

If I were then to use query middleware:

```
tourSchema.pre(/^find/, function (next) {
  console.log(this)
  next();
});
```

What would `this` be?

Answer (score 0):

As explained into [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html)

> In query middleware functions, this refers to the query.

Also, if you do a `console.log(this)` you can check the object is like:

```
Query {
  //a lot of stuffs
}
```

So, that is, `this` is the query.

Also, as another example, using `update` you can do this query:

```
model.update({},{$set:{field:"value"}})
```

And check this hook:

```
MongooseModel.pre('update', async function () {
  const query = this.getUpdate();
  console.log(query) // { '$set': { field: 'value' } }
  const field = query.$set.field;
  console.log(field) // value
});
```